# Why do we use 是 and not 有 here ？生活中的美到处都是

Tags: difference

When I first saw this offer, I was confused. Because it seemed to me that here it is better to use "this"But if everything is in order here, then I do not understand the purpose of using "and" here. Please tell me, can i use just 有 here?I saw that sentence in my textbook and i was confused when i

Answer (score 1):

I think the translations below provide the ideas.

- "生活中的美"到䖏都**是** - "The beauty of living" **is** everywhere.
- 到䖏都**有**"美好的生活方法" - **There is** "a pretty way for living" everywhere.

Note that "有" means "possess", while "是" makes a simple statement.

Answer (score 0):

Think it as "is" in "there is". It is just innate to the Language.

French uses "avoir/have" in "il y a", English uses "be/is" in "there is". Chinese has its own rules of course.

However I think in this sentence, you can use both 是(is) and 有(have). I would use 是. I'm a native speaker so I really don't know how my ancestors came up with this innate things nor how I prefer 是 unconsciously

Answer (score 0):

生活中的美到处都**是**。= 生活中的美到处都**有**。= There are good things everywhere in our life. Both are good sentences and mean the same.

In Chinese, **是** and **有** are used exchangeably in most cases. **是** emphasizes the **fact** that what the speaker is talking about is definitely true, while **有** points out the status of the **existence** of something, just like **to be** in English. For example,

(1) 一个月没回家，屋子里到处都**是**尘土。= Coming back home after one month, what I see is dust everywhere in the room. （that is disgusting)

(2) 一个月没回家，桌面上已经**有**了一层尘土。= Coming back home after one month, there is already a layer of dust on the desk. (just need to clean the desk)

The feeling is that **是** is stronger than **有**.

Answer (score 0):

This is my way of understanding it.  When you hear the word 有, you mentally conjure up a collection of objects, from which you select one or a few, but not necessarily all.

> 我包里有三本书。  (My bag has three books.)

Maybe my bag also contains other things, like my lunch or a water bottle.

So if you say 到处都有 it implies no matter where you look, there are some aspects which satisfy the property, but not necessarily all aspect.

> 到处都有中国人。  (Chinese people are everywhere.)

This doesn't imply that everything is composed of Chinese people; it's saying that no matter where you go, you'll find Chinese people.  (It's used hyperbolically, i.e., it exaggerates the truth.)

So I would interpret

> 生活中的美到处都是

as having the stronger meaning "the beauty of life is everywhere", rather than, say, "everywhere, the beauty of life can be found".  It's like you don't need to look for it---it's everywhere.  This is also being used hyperbolically, so I wouldn't overthink the distinction between 有 and 是 here.

Answer (score 0):

There is, in my view, (I emphasize, my view), a difference, though under everyday conversations, no one would pay any critical attention.

Thus:-

生活中的美到处都是 implies that there ***is*** beauty in life everywhere, you just have to open your eyes and see.

生活中的美到处都有 is stating a self-evident fact, i.e. the beauty of life ***is already*** everywhere / all around us; implying that there is really no need to look for it.

My 2 cents.